# Get parent form class when you click on an element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, parent, classname

Let's start with the HTML:

```
<form class="send_units">
    <div class="buttons">
        <div id="button_attack" class="button">
            <div class="caption at">Attack!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="button_support" class="button">
            <div class="caption sp">Support!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is an example of the code on a website. I've made a script for that website. To run that script, a player can use Tampermonkey. It just adds some code to the webpage. *Note: We cannot change the HTML!*

So, I've to get the classname of the form (send_units in this example), when you click on the Attack! button.

To figure out on which element the user clicks, we use Javascript:

```
window.onclick = function(e){
    var clickedClass = e.target.className;
    var clickedID = e.target.id;

    if(clickedClass == 'caption at'){
        // Check if parent form has class send_units
    }
}
```

So, when the user clicks on the button with `class = 'caption at'`, we have to check if the form class is send_units.

I've tried this to get the class:

```
jQuery(e).find('form').parent().prop('class')
```

but it returns "undefined". (Logic says to me: Get the parent of the clicked element, with element "form" and get the className of that element).

Can anyone explains to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: You explicitly check for the classes `caption` and `at`. Then why don't you add the event handler on exactly this element instead of `window`? With jQuery? -> `$("div.caption.at").on("click", function() { $(this).closest("form").attr("class"); })`

Comment: `e` is the click event not the clicked-on element.

Comment: @Andreas Because I use more than one event. This is a small example, but other events depends on the class and ID, or class and title. There is also an event with a specific HTML, so I use them all in one function to have an overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.parents( selector )` to traverse multiple levels up the DOM to the element you need and `.hasClass( class )` to test for presence of a class.

```js
window.onclick = function(e){
    var clickedClass = e.target.className;
    var clickedID = e.target.id;

    if(clickedClass == 'caption at'){
     var is_send_units = $( e.target ).parents( 'form' ).hasClass( 'send_units' );
        console.log( is_send_units );
        if( is_send_units ){
          // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="send_units">
    <div class="buttons">
        <div id="button_attack" class="button">
            <div class="caption at">Attack!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="button_support" class="button">
            <div class="caption sp">Support!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your explanation, sauntimo.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out since you know the div levels already.

```
$(e.target).parent().parent().parent().attr("send_units")
```